# Highcharts with datetime axis => tooltip bug when dates are out of sequence

Tags: highcharts

Have a look at this chart.

the tooltips seem to be mixed up on the points that are not in chronological order.

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'line'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Tooltip issue'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'tooltip are not well managed when points are out of chronological sequence'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'S1',

            data: [
                [Date.UTC(2013,  0, 15), 1   ],
                [Date.UTC(2013,  1, 15), 2   ],
                [Date.UTC(2013,  3, 15), 3   ],
                [Date.UTC(2013,  2, 15), 4   ],
                [Date.UTC(2013,  4, 15), 5   ]
            ]
        }]
    });
});
```

See it live here: [jsfiddle showing the bug](http://jsfiddle.net/VWsYc/1/)

Is this a bug?
Can it be fixed?

Thank you.

Comment: You should have sorted data by x, ascending.

Answer (score 0):

The tooltips look fine to me. I get 3 in April and 4 in march as specified in the data.

Comment: Does the tooltip for the March point appears when you put your cursor on the March point ?
Does the tooltip for the April point appears when you put your cursor on the April point ?

Comment: Yes, on mupy ipad. I'll check on my pc later.

Comment: Can you post a picture of the problem?

Comment: Ahh, you're right. The tooltip matches the points which are highlighted, but it highlights the wrong one, not the one nearest to the cursor.